# Is there a geometric interpretation of the exponential function of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, visualization

I can visualize the exponential function with the graph $y = e^x$, but I can do that for almost any function.

In addition to its graph, the function $f(x) = x^n$ can be visualized as the volume of a box with sides of length $x$ in n-dimensional space, and the trigonometric functions can be interpreted as side lengths of certain right triangles.

Is there a similar geometric interpretation of the exponential function?

Comment: if you want an $n$-cube of volume $(1+x/n)$ its sides are about length $e^x$...if you want to throw $\sin x, \cos x,\sinh x,\cosh x,e^x$ all in one bucket you can look at solutions to simple 1st/2nd order linear diff eqns...$x'-x=0,x''\pm x=0$

Comment: Further to your example of $x^n$, you could consider $\mathrm{e}^x$ as interpolating the volume of a box with sides of length $\mathrm{e}$ in $x$-dimensional space for non-integer dimensions $x$ -- but something tells me that might not be the sort of thing you're looking for :-)

Comment: This is not an answer to this question, but maybe it's useful nevertheless: the exponential function is characterized as the only continuous group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ onto $(\mathbb{R}^+, *)$ such that its derivative at the origin is $1$. This is (IMHO) the best way to define and visualize it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a geometric interpretation of the natural log. From the definition

$$ \log x = \int_1^x {1 \over t} \: dt $$

we see that the area between the "standard" hyperbola $xy = 1$ and the horizontal axis between $1$ and $x$ is $\log x$.

So, turning this around, the line $x = e^t$ is the vertical line such that the area between $x = 1$ and $x = e^t$, between this hyperbola and the $x$-axis, is $t$.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is not about $e^x$, but about the closely connected *hyperbolic* functions
$$
\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2},\quad\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}.
$$
A little algebra shows that $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$. Thus, $(\cosh x,\sinh x)$ are points in the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=1$; then $\cosh x$ and $\sinh x$ are the legs of a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the segment joining the origin and the point with coordinates $(\cosh x,\sinh x)$.

A different interpretation is the following: Imagine that you are running away fron some fixed point $O$. If your speed at each moment is equal to the distance to the point $O$, then your speed will be $C\,e^x$ for some constant $C>0$.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a visual way to understand it, while a geometric interpretation might be useful, the most intuitive way to understand $e^x$ for me was stuff like population dynamics.

If you've ever heard the phrase "exponential growth" in relation to a population of something (bacteria, fish, wildlife, etc), it refers to the idea that each change in the population is linearly proportional to the population at the last time step -- assuming no outside influences in any way hinder or alter the population dynamics.

It stems from what I think is probably the simplest non-trivial ordinary differential equation there is:

> $y'(t) = y(t)$

That is, there exists some function $y(t)$ such that $y(t)$ is the same function as its first derivative (up to a constant).  The only function satisfying this criteria is $e^x$.

The implication may not be immediately obvious, so I hope you'll forgive the example.

If a population of fish is accurately described by $y$, then the larger my fish population is the faster the population will grow -- exponentially so.  At each iteration, assuming a fixed average spawn-rate-per-fish, then the new fish added to the population will be a percentage of the size of the current population, and since the population grows every round then the *increase* and the *population* both grow at about the same pace.

This is true of financial investments as well that are strictly based on a fixed interest rate.

Of course, these are simplistic models.  Fish populations don't really grow exponentially and financial investments don't really produce exponential growth.

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple geometric construction which allows you to visualize  $f(x)=e^x$.

Take two objects on a flat level surface, one at the point $(0,0)$ and the other at $(0,1)$, that are connected by a piece of string. Slide the top object along the horizontal line $y=1$. The horizontal displacement of this object is given by $x$, and the trajectory of the bottom object (the path of least resistance) is called a tractix.

After sliding $x$ units horizontally, draw the line segment of length $1$ which is parallel to the string and which contains $(0,0)$ as one of its endpoints. The second point of this line segment lies on the unit circle. Draw a line through the circle endpoint and the point $(1,0)$. The $y$-intercept $b$ of this line is equal to $e^x$, and the point $(x,b)$ belongs to the graph of the exponential function $f$.

Here is an animation I made using GeoGebra: https://youtu.be/zzvwGl9WpX8